# .bat batch file how to get environment variable from string?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I have the name of an variable saved as a string (it will be read in from a CONFIG file).  I would like to evaluate this environment variable, to print its value to the console for example.  I am unsure of how to do this.

My current script:

```
@echo off

set env_var=VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3

set str=set vivado_bat_path=%env_var%
%str%
echo "bat path:  %vivado_bat_path%"

set str=set vivado_bat_path=%%env_var%%
%str%
echo "bat path:  %vivado_bat_path%"
```

Its current output:

```
"bat path:  VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3"
"bat path:  %env_var%"
```

Desired Output:

```
"bat path:  C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.3/bin/vivado.bat" (or whatever value the env var is set to)
```

I know that I could get the desired output with `echo %VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3%` but I am reading in `VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3` as a variable, so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want the path to the bat file executed at the moment you can use `%~f0`

Comment: `call echo %%%env_var%%%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a value of a variable, the "usual" way is to use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).
But you can also force a second parsing ("expand an expanded variable").
You can do that with the `call` command (which executes the following command within a second separate process). To pass a literal `%` to the second process, escape it with another `%`, which explains the strange triple`%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "string=varname"
set "varname=some text"

echo with delayed expansion:    %string% = !%string%!
call echo without delayed expansion: %string% = %%%string%%%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3=I Want This String"
set env_var=VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3

set str=set vivado_bat_path=%env_var%
%str%
echo "bat path:  %vivado_bat_path%"

set str=set vivado_bat_path=%%env_var%%
%str%
echo "bat path:  %vivado_bat_path%"

set "bingo=Not Found"
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set %env_var% 2^>nul') do if /i "%%a"=="%env_var%" set "bingo=%%b"
echo I found "%bingo%"

GOTO :EOF
```

This should expand your variable, in addition to your code.

I forced the value of `VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3` since it does not exist on my system.

The `if /i` ensures that should an environment variable named `VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3_old` exist for instance, then only the variable exactly named `VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3` is reported.

The `2^>nul` suppresses error messages should `VIVADO_BAT_PATH_2018_3` not exist. The `^` escapes `>`, telling batch that the `>` is part of the `set` command, not the `for` command. `bingo` is set before the `for` to ensure that any existing value for `bingo` is not mistaken for the desired value should `bingo` be already set when the batch runs.